# DI Implementation in asp.net project

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I am using ASP.Net, Entity Framwork along with Microsoft Unity Framework integration, i have below setup for the data consumption:

1. DataObjects:

   1. ArticleDo - This contains all the entities needed for the database.
   2. GenericDo - This contains all the entities which are common across project.
2. Dao. (Concrete classes)

   1. ArticleDao - This contains the implemented functions specific for Articles from IArticleDao. (This inherits GenericDao, IArticleDao
   2. GenericDao - This is an abstract class it contains the implementation of the Generic functions used across the project.
3. Interfaces.

   1. IArticleDao - This contains the declaration of the Article specific functions. (this inherits IGenericDao)
   2. IGenericDao -This contains the declaration of all the generic functions which are common across projects, like pulling in specific field from database etc. (This inherits IGenericDao

Here's the implementation:

DataObjects.

1. ArticleDo:

```
public class ArticleDo
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int WordCount { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }       
}
```

2. GenericDo:

```
public class GenericDo
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }     
}
```

Business Layer (Concrete classes)

1. ArticleDao:

```
public class ArticleDao : GenericDao<ArticleDo, DataContext>, IArticleDao
    {
        private readonly Data.DataContext db;
        public ArticleDao()
        {
            db = new Data.DataContext();
        }

        public override string Add(ArticleDo entity)
        {
            entity.AddedBy = Common.CurrentUsername;
            db.Articles.Add(entity);
            var returnVal = db.SaveChanges();
            if (returnVal > 0)
                return "Success";
            return "Fail";
        }

        public List<ArticleDo> Search(string SearchTerm, int CurrentPage, out int Total)
        {
            SearchTerm = SearchTerm.ToLower();
            var totalRecords = List().Where(x => x.ArticleId.ToString() == SearchTerm ||
                                                    (x.Title.ToString().ToLower().Contains(SearchTerm)));
            Total = totalRecords.Count();
            return totalRecords.Skip(CurrentPage * Common.Page_SIZE).Take(Common.Page_SIZE).ToList();
        }
    }
```

2. GenericDao:

```
public abstract class GenericDao<T, C> : IGenericDao<T, C> where T : class where C : DbContext, new ()
    {
        private readonly DataContext _db = new DataContext();
        private C _entities = new C();
        public virtual string Add(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
            return "Success";
        }

        public virtual bool Delete(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
            return true;
        }

        public T Get(T entity)
        {
            var _get = _entities.Set<T>();
            if (_get == null) return null;
            return _get.First();
        }

        public virtual List<T> List()
        {
            return _entities.Set<T>().ToList();
        }

        public virtual bool Update(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return true;
        }
        public T FindByProperty(string property, object value)
        {
            var _find = _db.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<T>>(string.Format("SELECT a.* from {0} a where a.p0 = p1", typeof(T).FullName), new object[] { property, value });
            if (_find != null && _find.Any())
            {
                return (T)_find.First();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

DataInterfaces.

1. IArticleDao

```
 public interface IArticleDao : IGenericDao<ArticleDo, DataContext>
    {
        List<ArticleDo> Search(string SearchTerm, int CurrentPage, out int Total);
    }
```

2. IGenericDao

```
public interface IGenericDao : IGenericDao<GenericDo, DataContext> { }
    public interface IGenericDao<T, C>
    {
        string Add(T entity);
        bool Update(T entity);
        bool Delete(T entity);
        List<T> List();
        T Get(T entity);
        T FindByProperty(string property, object value);
    }
```

Now before i implement the entities which would resolve the `IArticleDao` and i would be able to call my business layer functions, i tried to create concrete object directly in the page behind like:

```
IArticleDao dao = new ArticleDao();
```

Now as per my understanding, since `ArticleDao` is inheriting `GenericDao<ArticleDo, DataContext>` i should be able to access all the `ArticleDo` entities from the `dao` object, but that's not happening, could anyone please help me to achieve this, i don't want to inherit `ArticleDao` in `ArticleDo`, because that would defeat the purpose of DI integration. Also how could i use the contructor injection, do i need to create the constructor in my aspx code behind file?

Comment: I think you want `IGenericDao<ArticleDo, DataContext> dao = new ArticleDao();`

Comment: @JohnWu i tried that too, but even that's just exposing the business functions, i want to access business functions as well as busines entities which are within ArticleDo, since IArticleDao is already inheriting IGenericDao<ArticleDo, DataContext>, i think IArticleDao dao = new ArticleDao() would work same as IGenericDao<ArticleDo, DataContext> dao = new ArticleDao();

Comment: Could you add a line of code to your example that demonstrates a call that you would like to make but causes a compiler error? I'm not clear on what method isn't working for you.

Comment: Actually i am not getting any errors, when i do IArticleDao dao = new ArticleDao() it simply pulls out the business functions from ArticleDao class, however since i am inheriting GenericDao<ArticleDo, DataContext> i am expecting all the business entities to be pulled in as well, if am wrong could you take me to correct directions, i want to get all business entities in ArticleDo and business functions in ArticleDao.

Comment: I don’t know what “pulled in” means. Show me code.

Comment: i mean in the IArticleDao dao = new ArticleDao(); (dao object should be able to access business entities from ArticleDo as well as business funcitons from ArticleDao)